# boost::mutex called by other project gives access violation

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

I'm working on a solution including 2 projects, a .DLL built with the v80 toolset (C++98) and an .EXE using the v110 toolset (early C++11). The reason is the solution is progressively migrated to C++11, and the v80 .DLL still has dependencies preventing the upgrade. That will be fixed eventually, meanwhile...

The v80 .DLL listens to a network, is queuing events (to later be digested by the v110 .EXE) and controls the queue's access with a boost::mutex. Both projects are using the same version of boost assets (1.58.8.6 for ms80).

When the v80 EventListener class locks the mutex, there seem to be no problem. To test that, I've been calling member methods using the mutex from the EventListener's constructor. Scoped locks and calls to lock()/unlock() are acting normally.

*THE PROBLEM :*

When the v110 Dispatcher calls EventListener's methods (classes like clearQueue() or ~EventListener() locking the mutex) I'm getting an access violation error when trying to lock the mutex. This line gives the error:

```
// in boost\thread\win32\thread_primitive.hpp
inline bool interlocked_bit_test_and_set(long* x,long bit)
{
    return _interlockedbittestandset(x,bit)!=0;  <-- 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00EC1644
}
```

Some additionnal details:

- the mutex class member is a `boost::mutex*` being initialized with `new boost::mutex()` at the constructor's initialization
- when the mutex is locked, it is with `boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(*mQueueMutex);`

I'm thinking that maybe when the call is made by the v110 .EXE, the context/permission for the `_interlockedbittestandset` call is different somewhow and could cause the error... but I have nothing to back this theory so far.

### EDIT

Came up with a minimal, complete and verifiable example on my own, **but I wasn't able to recreate the issue**. I must say it's been a great reflexion exercice to make the example and try to compact the issue, it was also faster than I thought!

I highly recommend to anyone to try that before posting here, and offer an humble apology to anyone who felt spammed by my post.

For now, I'll try to figure out where's really the issue.

### v110 code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "../BoostMutexTest/MutexOwningClass_v80.h"

void work(MutexOwningClass_v80* m)
{
  m->lockMutex();
}

void main()
{
  MutexOwningClass_v80* v80_Class = new MutexOwningClass_v80();

  std::thread t1(&work,v80_Class);
  std::thread t2(&work,v80_Class);
  std::thread t3(&work,v80_Class);
  std::thread t4(&work,v80_Class);

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
}
```

### v80 code

```
#include "boost/thread.hpp"

struct MutexOwningClass_v80
{
  MutexOwningClass_v80();
  void lockMutex();
private:
  boost::mutex* m;
};

#include "MutexOwningClass_v80.h"
#include <iostream>

MutexOwningClass_v80::MutexOwningClass_v80(): m(new boost::mutex())
{}

void MutexOwningClass_v80::lockMutex()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(*m);
  std::cout << "My mutex is locked!" << std::endl; 
}
```

### output (unsurprisingly...)

```
My mutex is locked!
My mutex is locked!
My mutex is locked!
My mutex is locked!
```

Comment: You are braver than I.  I have never had good luck mixing C++ versions like that:  it has always ended in tears for me.  But I've only been doing C++ for about 30 years.  If you are using a C ABI between the two different C++ versions, you might have a fighting chance.

Comment: It is difficult to suggest anything without [mcve] as there are way to many moving parts. Most probably your data is corrupted but again not enough information.

Comment: Hi @Slava, lots of moving parts indeed. I was trying to ask my question to get a more theorical/conceptual answer, knowing that laying all the code here might be overwhelming and/or unappreciated. Are you thinking of a critical section you'd like me to edit in?

Comment: @VincentDM I did not ask for all the code, I asked for [mcve], click on that link it explains what that means.

Comment: @Eljay it's not about luck. It's about ABI and ODR. The simple truth is, mixing is not supported here, and doing so isn't about luck but about [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)